# Change product version and product code using Jenkins CI and InstallShield

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2013, installshield, nant

I have a system with 8 options to deploy and manage all these .config files are causing problems for the team 
So I found a Jenkins plugin for installshield. But i don't know how change the product version and product code using jenkins. 
In VisualStudio, I change this options in "ProjectInstall > GeneralInformation > Product Version.

[image]

What I want to know is:
How change these information by code (jenkins configuration or Nant, or something else)

I'm using "VisualStudio 2013" and "InstallShield Limited Edition for VisualStudio 2013"

Comment: Opening the .isl file I found this line `<row><td>ProductVersion</td><td>1.0.5.1</td><td/></row>` But I don't know if change this is safe neither WHEN I have to make the change

Comment: You should specify what version of installshield and visual studio you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the IS plugin for Jenkins but it's probably just a wrapper for [ISCmdBld.exe](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/ISCmdBldParam.htm).  If so, it probably exposes the -y and -z arguments (bottom of page) for overriding the ProductVersion and other named properties.

That said, I haven't called IsCmdBld.exe in years.  InstallShield has nice MSBuild support which means you can do all of this in MSBuild and just build the .SLN like any other Visual Studio project.